Rule Exception: Called Process Error Snakemake pipeline
I'm attempting to run the SPLINTR barcode seq pipeline on the test fastq files.
https://atlassian.petermac.org.au/bitbucket/projects/DAW/repos/splintr_barcode_seq_pipeline/browse
My Conda environment has the necessary dependencies. The first filter/trim barcodes rule seems to be successful, but I am running into an issue with the next rule align barcodes.
Firstly, I get this message in the beginning right after processing:
Resources before job selection: {'_cores': 8, '_nodes': 9223372036854775807}
Ready jobs (4)
Select jobs to execute...
cbc(51896,0x2023b92c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x3ff0000000000000: pointer being freed was not allocated
cbc(51896,0x2023b92c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Failed to solve scheduling problem with ILP solver. Falling back to greedy solver. Run Snakemake with --verbose to see the full solver output for debugging the problem.
Selected jobs (2)
Resources after job selection: {'_cores': 0, '_nodes': 9223372036854775805}

These are the shell scripts that seem to be where the hiccup is occurring:
bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test2.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test2/test2_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam

bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test1.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test1/test1_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam

Here is the FULL error message:
BEGIN at Mon Apr 29 17:22:05 EDT 2024
BEGIN at Mon Apr 29 17:22:05 EDT 2024
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
Full Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2656, in run_wrapper
    run(
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 193, in __rule_align_barcodes
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 294, in __new__
    raise sp.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test1.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test1/test1_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.

Full Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2656, in run_wrapper
    run(
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 193, in __rule_align_barcodes
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 294, in __new__
    raise sp.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test2.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test2/test2_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.

[Mon Apr 29 17:22:05 2024]
Error in rule align_barcodes:
    jobid: 7
    input: trimmed_reads/test1.trimmed.fastq
    output: mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam, mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam
    log: logs/test1/test1_align_barcodes.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    shell:
        
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test1.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test1/test1_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam
        
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

[Mon Apr 29 17:22:05 2024]
Error in rule align_barcodes:
    jobid: 4
    input: trimmed_reads/test2.trimmed.fastq
    output: mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam, mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam
    log: logs/test2/test2_align_barcodes.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    shell:
        
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test2.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test2/test2_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam
        
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Full Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2656, in run_wrapper
    run(
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 193, in __rule_align_barcodes
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 294, in __new__
    raise sp.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test1.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test1/test1_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 715, in _callback
    raise ex
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 699, in cached_or_run
    run_func(*args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2692, in run_wrapper
    raise RuleException(
snakemake.exceptions.RuleException: CalledProcessError in file /Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk, line 113:
Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test1.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test1/test1_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 113, in __rule_align_barcodes

Full Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2656, in run_wrapper
    run(
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 193, in __rule_align_barcodes
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 294, in __new__
    raise sp.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test2.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test2/test2_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 715, in _callback
    raise ex
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 699, in cached_or_run
    run_func(*args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2692, in run_wrapper
    raise RuleException(
snakemake.exceptions.RuleException: CalledProcessError in file /Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk, line 113:
Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test2.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test2/test2_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 113, in __rule_align_barcodes

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file /Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk, line 113:
Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test1.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test1/test1_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 113, in __rule_align_barcodes
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
Removing output files of failed job align_barcodes since they might be corrupted:
mapped_reads/test1/test1.bam, mapped_reads/test1/test1.unmapped.bam
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file /Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk, line 113:
Command 'set -eo pipefail; echo BEGIN at $(date);  
        bowtie -v 2 --norc -t -p 4 --sam --un mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam ./refs/mCHERRY_reference_library/bowtie/mCHERRY_barcode trimmed_reads/test2.trimmed.fastq 2> logs/test2/test2_align_barcodes.log | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort - > mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam
         ; exitstat=$?; echo END at $(date); echo exit status was $exitstat; exit $exitstat' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  File "/Users/laks/Desktop/Barcode_analysis/splintr_pipeline/barcode-seq_analysis.snk", line 113, in __rule_align_barcodes
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/intel_env/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
Removing output files of failed job align_barcodes since they might be corrupted:
mapped_reads/test2/test2.bam, mapped_reads/test2/test2.unmapped.bam
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2024-04-29T172204.328966.snakemake.log
unlocking
removing lock
removing lock
removed all locks

I'm having a hard time deciphering the error message and how ot fix this. It seems to be an issue with the script itself which I am not very familiar with. This is my first time running a Snakemake workflow as well.

Try editing the barcode-seq_analysis.snk file and commenting out the lines 45 and 47 (which set shell.prefix and shell.suffix). I think these are broken and unnecessary, and are causing the "syntax error" problem.
I have no idea why you have 9223372036854775807 nodes available - that's a pretty powerful system :-) But in reality that doesn't seem to be causing you a problem.
